# Find the latest file in a path and fetch it to another server. Use the filename only

Tags: ansible, yaml

```yaml
---
- name: Find the latest file
  find:
    paths: /tmp/data
    file_type: file
    age: -2m
    age_stamp: mtime
  register: files

- debug:
    msg: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path if//files.files|count > 0 else "cannot find any file" }}'

- name: Copy file, if found
  fetch:
    src: '{{ (files.files | sort(attribute="mtime", reverse=true) | first).path }}'
    dest: '/tmp'
  when: files.files|count > 0
```

In the above code when the fetch module is running it's just copying the full path. I just need the file. Can someone assist with what src can be set so that it just copies the latest file which is found and not the entire path?

Comment: You do have an issue in the code you are providing here, I guess a wrong copy/paste  in `if//files.files|count > 0 else "cannot find any file"` you should fix it by [edit]ing your question

Comment: I edited the question but left the fix to the author.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Copy the latest file which is found and not the entire path."***

A: Set *`flat: true`* and end the *dest* path by the slash *`/`*. See the notes below. Quoting from  [*flat*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#parameter-flat):

> If dest ends with '/', it will use the basename of the source file, similar to the copy module. This can be useful if working with a single host, or if retrieving files that are uniquely named per host.

For example, given the files

```yaml
shell> tree data1
data1
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3
```

The playbook below will copy the latest file (but not older than 2 minutes) from the directory *`data1`* to the directory *`/tmp/localhost/data1/`*

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: find the latest file
      find:
        paths: data1
        file_type: file
        age: -2m
        age_stamp: mtime
      register: files

    - name: Copy file if found
      fetch:
        src: "{{ (files.files|sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=true)|first).path }}"
        dest: /tmp
      when: files.files|count > 0
```

The result will be the file stored in *`/tmp/localhost/data1/file3`*

```sh
shell> ll /tmp/localhost/data1/file3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Mar  1 15:18 /tmp/localhost/data1/file3
```

---

If you want to copy the file only change the attributes *dest* and *flat*, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Copy file if found
      fetch:
        src: "{{ (files.files|sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=true)|first).path }}"
        dest: /tmp/
        flat: true
      when: files.files|count > 0
```

The result will be the file stored in *`/tmp/file3`*

```sh
shell> ll /tmp/file3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin admin 0 Mar  1 15:18 /tmp/file3
```

---

**Notes**

- The module [*fetch*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#synopsis) is used for fetching files from remote machines and storing them locally.
- By default, the fetched files are stored in a 'host-based directory'. For example, if the dest directory is /backup an src file named /etc/profile on host host.example.com, would be saved into /backup/host.example.com/etc/profile. The hostname is based on the inventory name. See [*dest*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html#parameter-dest)
- By default, the attribute *flat* is *False*

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Botka for answering...the solution worked!!!!